# json data with data type in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Normally json data is in array and straight forward in the value in the array in while loop. My concern now is how to create an json data with data type for example the below.

here my mysql statement

```
 $query = "SELECT 

    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    issue as issue,
    thedate as thedate,
    shift as shift
FROM
    userdata
WHERE
    thedate >= '2020-07-20'
GROUP BY issue , thedate,shift";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $array = array();
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
    {
        $nestedData=array();
        $nestedData["cnt"] = $row["cnt"];
        $nestedData["issue"] = $row["issue"];
        $nestedData["thedate"] = $row["thedate"];
        $nestedData["shift"] = $row["shift"];
        $array[] = $nestedData;
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

and the json data will be look like this

```
[
    {"cnt":"6","issue":"Problem High","checklist_date":"2020-07-20","shift":"Shift Morning"},
    {"cnt":"2","issue":"Problem Low","checklist_date":"2020-07-21","shift":"Shift Night"},
    {"cnt":"1","issue":"Problem Mid","checklist_date":"2020-07-220","shift":"Shift Daily"}
]
```

But the one i'm expectated to have is something like this which cames with data type

```
[
    {
        "cnt":
        {
        "type":"number"
        },
        "issue":
        {
        "type":"string"
        },
        "thedate":
        {
        "type":"date number"
        },
        "shift":
        {
        "type":"string"
        }
    },

    {"cnt":"6","issue":"Problem High","checklist_date":"2020-07-20","shift":"Shift Morning"},
    {"cnt":"2","issue":"Problem Low","checklist_date":"2020-07-21","shift":"Shift Night"},
    {"cnt":"1","issue":"Problem Mid","checklist_date":"2020-07-220","shift":"Shift Daily"}
]
```

So i wondering how to declare the data type in the array out the while loop?

Comment: Is the type data fixed (as in same columns and same types)?

Comment: Use `$array = array(array('cnt'=>array('type'=>'number')), array('issue'=>array('type'=>'string')), array('thedate'=>array('type'=>'date number')), array('shift'=>array('type'=>'string')));` in place of `$array = array();`

Comment: `Normally JSON data is in array`. Wrong. Normally it is object, but with passing a second argument you can make it an associative array.

Comment: @NigelRen yes it fixed for the data type only value of the data keep changing.